# Is there a way to set custom field globally for tracing_subscriber without much effort?

Tags: logging, rust, rust-tracing

I use `tracing` and `tracing_subscriber` Rust libraries to write logs in the app and I would like to pass custom field globally for all log messages to separate different instances of the app in a log db. For example, I would like to put instance id in all log messages of that instance.
As such,

```json
{"timestamp": "...", "level": "INFO", "name": "instance1", "msg": "..."}
{"timestamp": "...", "level": "ERROR", "name": "instance1", "msg": "..."}
{"timestamp": "...", "level": "INFO", "name": "instance1", "msg": "..."}
```

Is there a way to implement this with standard `tracing_subscriber` and not implementing my own `Layer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`spans`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/span/index.html) to instrument your code and add metadata as needed for all subsecuent logging:

```rust
span!(Level::INFO, "my_span", name= "instance1");
```